# Inserting huge pandas dataframe into SQL Server table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

I am looking for a way to insert a big set of data into a SQL Server table in Python. The problem is that my dataframe in Python has over 200 columns, currently I am using this code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
server = 'yourservername' 
database = 'AdventureWorks' 
username = 'username' 
password = 'yourpassword'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+'UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (A,B,C)values(?,?,?)", row.A, row.B, row.C)
cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

The problem is in `INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (A, B, C) VALUES (?,?,?)", row.A, row.B, row.C` as I need to insert a data with over 200 columns and specifying each of these columns is not really time efficient :(

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create connection in SqlAlchemy
2. Use `df.to_sql()` with `chunksize` param. Link to [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

ps. in my cases connection not in `sqlalchemy` not working in `to_sql` - function

Comment: Yes, `.to_sql()` requires a SQLAlchemy Connectable (Engine or Connection) for all databases except SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found a way:

```
serverName = 'xxx'
dataBase = 'zzz'
conn_str = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + serverName + r';DATABASE=' + dataBase + r';TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes')
conn = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(conn_str)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn,poolclass=NullPool)
connection = engine.connect()
df.to_sql("TableName", engine, schema='SchemaName', if_exists='append', index= True, chunksize=200)
connection.close()
```